# ggplot unknown aesthetics disrupts filling order

Tags: r, ggplot2

BACKGROUND: I am preparing an interactive plot via a tooltip in `plotly` via the `ggplotly()` function. The recommend workflow for creating the tooltip information is to add an unknown aestetic in the ggplot plot, and then use this unknown aestetic later in the `ggplotly()` function.

PROBLEM: Adding an unknown aestetic disrupts the order of the fill variable. Is there a workaround to this?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: This reprex can be solved by letting `ggplot` do the counting via `geom_bar()`. This will however not work in my real problem.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

a <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(color, cut, clarity) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = color, y = n, fill = cut))+
  geom_col()
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'color', 'cut'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

b <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(color, cut, clarity) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = color, y = n, fill = cut))+
  geom_col(
    aes(text = paste("Count:", n))
  )
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'color', 'cut'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text

a
```

[image]

```r
b
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

This is how the call to `ggplotly()` will look

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(b,
         tooltip = "text")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` should be called within `ggplot` function so I think this gets you what you need:

```
b <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(color, cut, clarity) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = color, y = n, fill = cut, text = paste("Count:", n)))+
  geom_col()
ggplotly(b,
         tooltip = "text")
```

[image]